# AWS verifying SES identity from the wrong region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an email from an AWS lambda function. However, I get this error

> INFO  MessageRejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: testemail@gmail.com, support@mydomain.com

Both identities are verified in ap-southeast-2 and the lambda function is in the same region. If I am running the function from ap-southeast-2 and all my email configurations, including SMTP point to ap-southeast-2, why is the verification happening in us-east-1

Below is my code

```
const SES = new AWS.SES({ region: "us-east-1" });

const sendEmail = async (event) => {
  const params = getNotificationParams(event);
  console.log(params);

  if (!params || params.error) {
    return Responses._400({
      message: params.error,
    });
  }

  try {
    await SES.sendTemplatedEmail(params).promise();
    return Responses._200();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return Responses._500({ message: "Error sending email" });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  handler: sendEmail,
};
```

Comment: You might need to specify the region in your code somewhere. Can you show your code?

Comment: @MarkB you are right, I did not specify my desired region during SES initialisation in my code. Thank you

Comment: If you don't show your code, and the fix, then this post really isn't of help to others who come across it. Either show your code in the question (as you should have originally) and post the fix as an answer, or delete the question.

Comment: Understood @MarkB

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was that I specified the wrong region (us-east-1) during SES initialization. Here is the fixed code with ap-southeast-2

```
const SES = new AWS.SES({ region: "ap-southeast-2" });

const sendEmail = async (event) => {
  const params = getNotificationParams(event);
  console.log(params);

  if (!params || params.error) {
    return Responses._400({
      message: params.error,
    });
  }

  try {
    await SES.sendTemplatedEmail(params).promise();
    return Responses._200();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return Responses._500({ message: "Error sending email" });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  handler: sendEmail,
};
```